# Xcode is not launching my app for debugging

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging

My iOS project installs fine on the iPhone but the application won't launch automatically for debugging.

I'm using Xcode 4.2 (Build 4C199), the latest version for Snow Leopard (10.6.8).

I've already tried deleting the app from the iPhone, restarting the device, cleaning the project and reinstalled xCode.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Check the device console after you try to run the app with Xcode. It might contain logs about why the app hasn't launched.

Comment: I've been able to solve this problem by Changing **Debugger to LLDB**, instead of GDB, on the Run Tab, using Build Configuration -> DEBUG, by selecting Edit Scheme (On the right of the Stop Button), as indicated by Oscar Gomez.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to solve this problem by Changing **Debugger to LLDB**, instead of GDB, on the Run Tab, using Build Configuration -> DEBUG, by selecting Edit Scheme (On the right of the Stop Button).

Answer (score 5):

In Xcode click on where the project name/Device or simulator version is (On the right of the Stop Button), and select Edit Scheme, on the Run Tab select Build Configuration -> DEBUG, and select a DEBUGGER -> GDB.

Comment: It's already there, and the Launch option is set to "Automatically". Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I created a new target and a new scheme by duplicating the existing ones, in order to test my app on devices with on older iOS version.
However, the copied scheme had as executable selected "None":

[image]

As soon as I selected the right executable there from the drop-down menu, the app launched.

Answer (score 4):

I was having this problem as well. I removed the option **Launch due to a background fetch event** in **Edit Scheme -> Run Debug -> Options** and Xcode started launched the app again.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Can you confirm you are signing the app with a development certificate? This issue happens when you sign the app with a distribution certificate.

Comment: Yes, I'm signing the code with my iPhone Developer certificate, not the Distribution one. Thanks.